# Changing Copy/Paste macro to stop it from activating cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google sheet in which people have limited space to enter information. These cells contain data validation rules and specific (conditional) formatting that I don't want them to be able to change. They can do that by accident if they copy paste stuff into it. I've made a macro that copy's the same data validation/formatting from somewhere else on the sheet and pastes it over the cells they can edit. This macro runs everytime someone makes an edit (with onEdit function) and acts like a reset of the validation rules/formatting.

Things I want to accomplish:

1. Stop the macro from changing current selected cell
2. Macro to only run on the first tab called "Selection"
3. Make the macro unnoticable for users when they are editing the sheet i.e. speed and no jumps to other cells

Would it be possible to do this through code instead of a macro running the exact steps I took? And secondly.. the macro copy's formatting from protected cells. Would that give problems to users who don't have the permission to edit the copy range?

Hope I'm clear and someone wants to help me out.

```
function DataReset() {
      var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      spreadsheet.getRange('D2').activate();
      spreadsheet.getRange('D50:D69').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMAT, false);
      spreadsheet.getRange('D50:D69').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_CONDITIONAL_FORMATTING, false);
      spreadsheet.getRange('D50:D69').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_DATA_VALIDATION, false);
      spreadsheet.getRange('AB2').activate();
      spreadsheet.getRange('AB50:AV69').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMAT, false);
      spreadsheet.getRange('AB50:AV69').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_CONDITIONAL_FORMATTING, false);
      spreadsheet.getRange('AB50:AV69').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_DATA_VALIDATION, false);
    };
```

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Have you considered [creating a form](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6281888) instead of sharing a spreadsheet for data input? Form responses automatically appear in a separate tab in the spreadsheet in a row-oriented fashion and are thus easy to process with spreadsheet functions such as `query()` and `filter()`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That wouldn't work for me unfortunately. I have dynamic input ranges from which users can choose their input in the dropdown menu. Users can change their inputs until a deadline is reached (which I already have accomplished)

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
function DataReset() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let a = ss.getRange('D2');
  ss.getRange('D50:D69').copyTo(a, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMAT, false);
  ss.getRange('D50:D69').copyTo(a, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_CONDITIONAL_FORMATTING, false);
  ss.getRange('D50:D69').copyTo(a, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_DATA_VALIDATION, false);
  a = ss.getRange('AB2');
  ss.getRange('AB50:AV69').copyTo(a, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMAT, false);
  ss.getRange('AB50:AV69').copyTo(a, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_CONDITIONAL_FORMATTING, false);
  ss.getRange('AB50:AV69').copyTo(a, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_DATA_VALIDATION, false);
}
```

Comment: This got the job done first try! Thank you so much!